# How to have compass create a data-uri for an image based on a css color name?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, data-uri

In working with a piece of legacy javascript, I've discovered that the only way to style a particular control is to set it's background image. This makes it a pain to support more than a couple of different background colors. What I'd like to do, then, is have compass generate the image at compile-time, and inline it as a data-uri. To a compass n00b, this seems reasonable, since each "background image" is just a square swatch of solid color.

Does anyone know of a project out there to automate this? Is it even a reasonable approach? If the "generate all the images in advance" approach is really the best, then I could probably manage that, but it seems far less elegant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [compass-rgbapng](https://github.com/aaronrussell/compass-rgbapng) like this:

```
body {
  @include rgba-background-inline(rgba(0,0,0,1));
}
```